# Why is my XSD allowing a prohibited attribute in my XML?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I've inserted an attribute called Classroom into an element called Lecture. Here's the XML schema :

```
<xsd:attribute name="Classroom" use="required">
<xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
        <xsd:maxLength value="7"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

```
.
.
.
<xsd:complexType name="labType"> 
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="eventType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Lecture" maxOccurs="10" minOccurs="1"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:attribute name="Clasroom" use="prohibited"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
.
.
.
<xsd:element name="Lab" substitutionGroup="Event" type="labType"/>
```

The problem I'm having is that this schema does not apply the restriction on the attribute.
I tried to validate this XML code:

```
 <Lab>
                <Title>Artificial Intelligence</Title>
                <Lecture Classroom="BA">    
                    <Day>Friday</Day>
                    <Time>17:00-18:00</Time>
                </Lecture>                  
    </Lab>
```

My problem is that this XML is reported as valid even though it uses the attribute "Classroom"(which it shouldn't be able to do).
I'm new to XML so please don't be harsh.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration of `Lecture`,

```
<xsd:element name="Lecture" maxOccurs="10" minOccurs="1"/>
```

**declares no type for `Lecture`, so you're effectively allowing any content and any attributes** on `Lecture`, regardless of any restrictions you might have defined on `Classroom` anywhere else in the XSD.

Here is a complete XSD that will successfully validate your XML:

```
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Lab">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Lecture">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Day" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="Time" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Classroom">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:minLength value="0"/>
                  <xs:maxLength value="7"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>              
            </xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The above XSD will allow the `Classroom` attribute on `Lecture` but will restrict values to be strings of length between 0 and 7, inclusive.

You could also add `xs:attribute/use="prohibited"` to prevent `@Classroom` from appearing on `Lecture`, but your original title, and this part of your question,

> The problem I'm having is that this schema does not apply the
>   restriction on the attribute.

imply that the focus of your question is on why the restriction wasn't having an effect.  Perhaps you meant *any* restriction in the generic sense -- `xs:restriction` or `use="prohibit"`.  Well, the answer is the same: **By not assigning a type to `Lecture`, you were allowing it to be of any type and have any attributes.**

Answer (score 2):

Typo in `Clasroom` (only 1 's')

```
<xsd:attribute name="Clasroom" use="prohibited"/>
```

The other part of the problem is that the attribute restriction is being applied to the `Lab` element rather than the `Lecture` element.

Comment: Good catch on `prohibited`  (+1). The original title mentioned "restriction", but you could be right that OP was wondering why restriction on the attribute in the generic sense, including `use="prohibited"`, were having no effect on the XML.  The root cause, I maintain, was the failure to specify a type for `Lecture`.